# scrollSnap js resistance with mousewheel

Tags: jquery, scroll, scroll-snap-points

I'm using https://github.com/electerious/scrollSnap to snapping sections in my website but i'm not understand because there is a resistance between mosaic grid and section below when i use mousewheel.

If i use scrollbar i can snap between sections under mosaic.

```
<script>
  scrollSnap.init({
    elements: document.querySelectorAll('section'),
    minWidth: 600,
    minHeight: 400,
    detectMobile: true,
    keyboard: true,
    duration: 20,
    timing: scrollSnap._timing
  })
  </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because you "snap" it to `<section>`, and your "upper html" is `<div>`. Wrap all your sections you want to be "snapable" inside of `<section></section>`.

Comment: I guess I've changed my code properly but it's the same. Could i got bad?

Comment: You got some javascript errors now on your page: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'dom' of null.

Comment: It snaps for me (latest chrome win10), but you might want to reduce the scroll height, I had to scroll 'hard' on my mouse (several lines in one scroll).

Comment: Thanks! Solved by your help.